# Checking if a list is inside a list of lists, for wining in tic tac toe

Tags: python

I'm new in python and trying to make a tic tac toe game, but i'm stacked in the checking if someone won.
I couldn't find an answer or any tic tac toe program that works similary.
These is what i have tried so far.

```
list1 = []
winning_combinations = [(0, 4, 8), (2, 4, 6)]

#making a list of all the winning combinations
for i in range(3):
        winning_combinations.append((i, i + 3, i + 6))
for j in range(3):
        winning_combinations.append((j * 3, 1 + j * 3, 2 + j * 3))


#just cheking if the program works with a given input
def cheking():
    num = int(input("list1: "))
    list1.append(num)
    print(list1)


#cheking every turn for a winner
while win:
    cheking()
    if any(list == winning_combinations for list in list1):
        print("win")
        win = False
```

Comment: That's a list of tuples, not a list of lists.

Comment: But `list1` is a list. A list will never compare equal to a tuple.

Comment: If you make them both the same type, you can use `if list1 in winning_combinations:`

Comment: Works for me: https://ideone.com/uGlqqf

Comment: Are the list elements in the same order? Maybe you should use a set of sets instead of a list of lists.

Comment: `list1` is `[an_int_num]`(for example, `[2]`) and you're trying to search `list1` in a list containing tuples (`[(0, 4, 8), (2, 4, 6),etc.]`) and hence it will always return `false`. Replace `[(0, 4, 8), (2, 4, 6)]` with `[[0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]` (Notice square brackets instead of round brackets). Refer the example given by @Barmar

Comment: The tuple thing worked perfectly, and i added a  ```list1.sort()``` so it matches more times, however the problem now is that my input is for example [0, 2, 8, 1] (in that order), when i apply the "sort" it becomes [0, 1, 2, 8] and it doesn't match the tuple in winning_combinations so it always returns False.